# DbDataReader.GetFieldValue<DateTime> throws casting exception

Tags: c#, generics, sqldatareader

I have this following method:

```
public static T Get<T>(this DbDataReader reader, int ordinal, Func<T> @default)
{
    if(reader.IsDBNull(ordinal))
        return @default();

    return reader.GetFieldValue<T>(ordinal);
}
```

When I try to call this with `T=DateTime` I get the following exception:

```
System.InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467262
  Message=Specified cast is not valid.
  Source=System.Data
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.GetFieldValue[T](Int32 ordinal)
       ...
```

The method seems to work fine for other types like strings and numeric types. Does the generic `GetFieldValue<T>` method simply not work for dates, or have I done something wrong here?

---

I have fixed it by handling the `DateTime` case using the specific `GetDateTime` method instead, but would still like to know if I could get rid of this annoying hack somehow.

```
public static T Get<T>(this DbDataReader reader, int ordinal, Func<T> @default)
{
   if(reader.IsDBNull(ordinal))
        return @default();

    switch(Type.GetTypeCode(typeof(T)))
    {
        case TypeCode.DateTime:
            return (T)(object)reader.GetDateTime(ordinal);

         default:
            return reader.GetFieldValue<T>(ordinal);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact exception?

Comment: @CodeCaster Added it to the question now :)

Comment: `DbDataReader.GetFieldValue<T>` calls `abstract public Object GetValue(int ordinal)` under the covers, so it is important to specify which `DbDataReader`-derived type you are actually using.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy It's using whatever is returned from `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()`, which looks to be `MySqlDataReader`.